# Python number of rng seeds

Tags: python, random

In the docs (python 3.5) for initializing a random number from a seed:

> random.seed(a=None, version=2)
>
> Initialize the random number generator.
>
> If a is omitted or None, the current system time is used. If
>   randomness sources are provided by the operating system, they are used
>   instead of the system time (see the os.urandom() function for details
>   on availability).
>
> If a is an int, it is used directly.
>
> With version 2 (the default), a str, bytes, or bytearray object gets
>   converted to an int and all of its bits are used. With version 1, the
>   hash() of a is used instead.

It does not make it clear how many seeds there are. An int has normally only 4 billion distinct values, but pythons  include arbitrary precision:

```
x = 1
type(x) # <class 'int'>
y = 123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789
type(y) # <class 'int'>
z = x+y
z-y # 1 (no rounding error for a 71 digit number)
```

They say **all of its bits are used** but that could mean that the bits are used to make a digest that is a normal 32 bit int. Why does this matter? I need a make random patterns from seeds. In turn, I need to makes random sequences of patterns (the sequence in turn has a seed). A stream of random number generators will be subject to a "birthday attack" in which after a 100 thousand or so there is almost certainly going to be a duplicate if it's only 32 bits. Although this is not for cryptography, it's still undesirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's great about open source is the ability to simply view the code with a question. This is the [source of `random.seed`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L115):

```
if a is None:
    try:
        # Seed with enough bytes to span the 19937 bit
        # state space for the Mersenne Twister
        a = int.from_bytes(_urandom(2500), 'big')
    except NotImplementedError:
        import time
        a = int(time.time() * 256) # use fractional seconds

if version == 2:
    if isinstance(a, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        if isinstance(a, str):
            a = a.encode()
        a += _sha512(a).digest()
        a = int.from_bytes(a, 'big')

super().seed(a)
self.gauss_next = None
```

You can see that if `version == 2` and `str`/`bytes` are provided, it takes the SHA512 of `a`, appends it, and uses `int.from_bytes`, generating a very large int and guaranteeing at *least* a 512-bit seed, even with very small custom inputs.

As noted below, the end result is that the seed is guaranteed to have a length of at least 624 bits.

Comment: "super().seed(a)" is the super further digesting this 512 bit hash or is it a genuine 512 bit seed?

Comment: I think it's also relevant what happens to `a` after `super().seed(a)`.  The source is https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/488376e0204bcea4ef4e07490a839bef9729e7ed/Modules/_randommodule.c ... `random_seed()` .. I'm still digesting it.

Comment: This comment *"This algorithm relies on the number being unsigned.
     So: if the arg is a PyLong, use its absolute value.
     Otherwise use its hash value, cast to unsigned."*
      seems to imply the seed eventually is just a `PyLong`.  Ah .. but [`Pylong` can be arbitrary size](https://docs.python.org/3.2/c-api/long.html).

Comment: Which leads us to `init_by_array()`, which is passed an array of 32bit ints.

Comment: ["The constant 19650218 is the birthday of one of the authors".](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/165.pdf)   Here's where it seems to set the length:      `k = (N>key_length ? N : key_length);`  where `N` is `624`  -- but that's a minimum not a maximum.  To my eye, it doesn't implement a maximum length.